# Running Artisan Horizon on Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, horizon

im tried to create cronjob on shared hosting with artisan horizon like this

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/example/example.com/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/example/example.com/artisan horizon>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but after a view hours our server goes down. any solutions for us?

Answer (score 0):

Horizon is not supposed to be on a cronjob, as every time the cron triggers that line, it is a new Horizon process that has to run, so probably that's why your server is going down.

The right solution is to set up Horizon using Supervisor: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon#supervisors